# Simple lemma about permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

While doing some recalling about permutations I've crossed with the following simple lemma:

Let $g:[n]\to [n]$ be a permutation. Let $x\in [n]$, and there exist $1\leq i\leq n$ so that $g^i(x)=x$.

The proof uses reductio ad absurdum argument and the Pigeon-hole Principle; suppose that there is no such $i$ and therefore from the Pigeon-hole Principle exists two equal elements from $\{g(x),g^2(x),...,g^n(x) \}$. Denoting that fact, $ g^j(x)=g^k(x) $ with $ j<k $ . The proof continues with natural way, taking the inverse permutation, $g^{-1}$ from both sides, to come eventually to result that should contradict the first assumption, $g(x)=g^{k-j+1}(x) $. Unfortunately, I can't see why its contradicts.

Edit: Its not that I have some guesses. Maybe the last equality tells us that $1=k-j+1$, thus $k=j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1<k-j+1\le n$, so the argument shows that $g(x)=g^\ell(x)$ for some $\ell$ satisfying $1<\ell\le n$. Now apply $g^{-1}$ once more to find that $x=g^{\ell-1}(x)$, where $1\le\ell-1<n$, which does indeed contradict the original assumption.

Comment: @Salech: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to note that a permutation is a product of disjoint cycles. $x$ belongs to one such cycle of length $k$ and the cycle length is $k \leq n$. So then $g^k(x) = x$.

Comment: Its a lemma that the book going to define with a cycle.